# How to use WHERE COUNT in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to do a query such as...

```
SELECT COUNT(UniqueLastNames)
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(c)
FROM c
WHERE COUNT(c.lastName) > 2 AND COUNT(c.lastName) < 5 GROUP BY c.lastName
) AS UniqueLastNames
```

What it should do is give me all the people whose last name appears more than twice, but less than 5.

Problem is, cosmos won't let you do a function in a WHERE statement it says, any other way around it?

Comment: Is this an sql question in general? I don't have a cosmosDb environment on right now but isn't it `SELECT COUNT(UniqueLastNames)
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(c)
FROM c
GROUP BY c.lastName HAVING COUNT(c.lastName) > 2 AND COUNT(c.lastName) < 5
) AS UniqueLastNames`

Comment: I don't believe the keyword 'HAVING' is supported in cosmos as it gives me incorrect syntax using it and no where online shows cosmos having that keyword that I can find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it to work with the following code...

```
SELECT COUNT(UniqueLastNames)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) AS lastName FROM c GROUP BY c.lastName) AS 
UniqueLastNames WHERE UniqueEmails.lastName > 2 AND UniqueEmails.lastName < 
5
```

... though it's so expensive on RUs at 137.86 RUs per request.

Comment: Have a separate collection for the aggregation and manage it instead of calculating it in real time, would be much cheaper